# laravel schema builder, find columnType autoincrement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-schema-builder

I'm working to update an existing database to use autoincremented primary keys. This DB currently has crazy named PK fields with custom values. I need to check each table first to see if it HAS an autoinc field first, then I want to drop it and replace with 'id' field.

I want to do this as a migration, here's what I have so far but I can't seem to identify if the first col is autoincrementing already so I can drop the existing PK and replace. I need to replace the hasColumn with something like a firstColumn then getColumnType...

```
    foreach ($tableNames as $name)
                if (!Schema::hasColumn($name, 'id')) {
                Schema::table($name, function ($table) {
                    $table->dropPrimary();
                    $table->increments('id')->first();
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Schema::getColumnType($table,$column)` ?

Comment: @AbrarShariarGalib yes i'm on that track now, apparently laravel needs Doctrine/DBAL included. I guess I'd need to get a column list then feed it that first col to check if its autoinc

Comment: actually @AbrarShariarGalib it just says 'integer' and doesn't tell me if it is an autoincrementing int

Comment: Right now I can think of using `DB::raw()` where the sql query will have something like - `EXTRA like '%auto_increment%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the problem I ran the following code from a controller. Notice here that I have only two fields for the demo (`id`,`name`)

`$result = DB::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name");
 dd($result);`

Now the output after `dd()` will be somewhat like this:

```
0 => {#162 ▼
    +"Field": "id"
    +"Type": "int(11)"
    +"Null": "NO"
    +"Key": "PRI"
    +"Default": null
    +"Extra": "auto_increment"
  }

1 => {#164 ▼
    +"Field": "name"
    +"Type": "varchar(255)"
    +"Null": "YES"
    +"Key": ""
    +"Default": null
    +"Extra": ""
  }
```

Now you can easily extract the `"Extra" : "auto_increment"` , like this:

```
$result = DB::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM product");
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if($value->Extra == 'auto_increment'){
                //do something
            };
```

Comment: I will either do this or select from the information schema, something like "select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
              where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'table_schema'
and TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
and extra = 'auto_increment'". I had hoped I could do it with Laravel but this is good enough. Thanks for the input!